# Magento 2: change order status programmatically

Tags: magento2

I need to set in "canceled" all orders stucks in "pending" status. The code that I used return this exception error:

```
[2022-12-03 08:00:53] main.CRITICAL: Please provide payment for the order.
```

Here the code:

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

protected $order;

public function __construct(Order $order)
{
    $this->order = $order;
}

public function orderStatusChange()
{
    $orderId = 9999;
    $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
    $order->setStatus("canceled");
    $order->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason :-**
It gives you that error is because there is an observer for it, which is called before order is saved that is **SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver**

[image]

**Solution :-**
Can you please try referring to Magento's core file **vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Cancel.php** to cancel the order which uses **Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface** to cancel the order. **You already have the $order populated in your code.**

[image]

If you need any help then please let me know in case if it not works for you as I have not implemented this.

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**